# setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift and Xcode and am attempting to build a simple app to get the hang of things. I am using the latest versions of Xcode, Swift and Realm, and I'm using CocoaPods for Realm (per a tutorial I'm following).

Every time I run the build I am getting the same error below (I'm unsure how best to paste / encapsulate error logs, so sorry if the formatting is wrong). I've looked in several forums and threads, but I am unable to find a fix.

Please let me know if I should include any additional information.

```html
2017-11-30 02:11:59.889152-0800 Stack[5668:6483642] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_handshake_error_print: line 3108 boringssl ctx 0x7fcafee11090: 140509925345312:error:10000410:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.20.5/ssl/tls_record.c:547:SSL alert number 40
2017-11-30 02:11:59.889310-0800 Stack[5668:6483642] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_session_handshake_error_print: line 3108 boringssl ctx 0x7fcafee11090: 140509925345312:error:1000009a:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:HANDSHAKE_FAILURE_ON_CLIENT_HELLO:/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/boringssl_Sim/boringssl-109.20.5/ssl/handshake_client.c:946:
2017-11-30 02:11:59.889418-0800 Stack[5668:6483642] [BoringSSL] Function boringssl_context_get_os_status: line 4059 SSL_AD_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE
2017-11-30 02:11:59.892200-0800 Stack[5668:6483642] NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
2017-11-30 02:11:59.892348-0800 Stack[5668:6483642] Task <D5FFC5D9-EA83-4334-A2D6-9B4C90DB13D4>.<2> HTTP load failed (error code: -1200 [3:-9824])
2017-11-30 02:11:59.892546-0800 Stack[5668:6483644] Task <D5FFC5D9-EA83-4334-A2D6-9B4C90DB13D4>.<2> finished with error - code: -1200
2017-11-30 02:12:09.233280-0800 Stack[5668:6483490] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<Stack.CreatePlaceViewController 0x7fcb01a08840> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key save.'
*** First throw call stack:
(
 0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001106241ab __exceptionPreprocess + 171
 1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010d41ff41 objc_exception_throw + 48
 2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001106240f9 -[NSException raise] + 9
 3   Foundation                          0x000000010ce421e3 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueCoding) setValue:forKey:] + 292
 4   UIKit                               0x000000010de51777 -[UIViewController setValue:forKey:] + 87
 5   UIKit                               0x000000010e140cb1 -[UIRuntimeOutletConnection connect] + 109
 6   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105c74fd -[NSArray makeObjectsPerformSelector:] + 317
 7   UIKit                               0x000000010e13f667 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 1856
 8   UIKit                               0x000000010e5cc0de -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 181
 9   UIKit                               0x000000010e5dba21 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate instantiateOrFindDestinationViewControllerWithSender:] + 90
 10  UIKit                               0x000000010e5dbc65 -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _perform:] + 52
 11  UIKit                               0x000000010e5dbf4b -[UIStoryboardSegueTemplate perform:] + 157
 12  UIKit                               0x000000010dcb6275 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
 13  UIKit                               0x000000010e6bd5d8 __45-[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:]_block_invoke + 154
 14  UIKit                               0x000000010e6bd509 -[_UIButtonBarTargetAction _invoke:forEvent:] + 181
 15  UIKit                               0x000000010dcb6275 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 83
 16  UIKit                               0x000000010de334a2 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
 17  UIKit                               0x000000010de337bf -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 450
 18  UIKit                               0x000000010de326ec -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 618
 19  UIKit                               0x000000010dd2bbbb -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 2807
 20  UIKit                               0x000000010dd2d2de -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 4124
 21  UIKit                               0x000000010dcd0e36 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 352
 22  UIKit                               0x000000010e613434 __dispatchPreprocessedEventFromEventQueue + 2809
 23  UIKit                               0x000000010e616089 __handleEventQueueInternal + 5957
 24  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105c7231 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
 25  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110666e41 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 81
 26  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105abb49 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 185
 27  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105ab12f __CFRunLoopRun + 1279
 28  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105aa9b9 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 409
 29  GraphicsServices                    0x00000001159d89c6 GSEventRunModal + 62
 30  UIKit                               0x000000010dcb45e8 UIApplicationMain + 159
 31  Stack                               0x000000010b71a3d7 main + 55
 32  libdyld.dylib                       0x0000000110c9fd81 start + 1
 33  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Do you've IBoutlet named as `save` in your `CreatePlaceViewController` class? Please check the outlet connection for this vc in storyboard

Comment: @InderKumarRathore Thanks, that did it!